# How to restrict email domain when user register on plone(4.3) site

Tags: plone

I set up a Plone(4.3) site.
And now we want to restrict user email domain when they register on our site?
For example
just email from domain1.com can register on the site.
that is a@domain1.com can register on the site.But b@domain2.com can't register on the site.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this by (monkey) patching the isMemberIdAllowed in Products.CMFPlone.RegistrationTool by verifying the domain in the userid with a configurable list in the control panel.

I extracted this as a package here: https://github.com/Adniel/allowed.domains
The user will only know that the userid was not allowed, not that it dit not find a matching domain. Pity.

It is not particularly neat, and there are most certainly better/other ways of doing it. But it could work.